# Eclipse cannot share remote systems project

Tags: eclipse

I added a remote systems project to my Eclipse explorer. When I try to share it with Git, I get following error:

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

What I would like to do is use my Windows machine to develop codes with Eclipse remote systems project, use Virtual Linux to test the website as it has Apache PHP and MySQL, and push it to remote Git repository from Windows Eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you get a NullPointerException?

Comment: Yes I do: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336711). Take a look at the link to see if it's similar to your case.

Some of the possible solutions for this were given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229562/problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug-in-org-eclipse-jface):

1. Go to Window | Preferences, XML | XML Files | Editor, and turn off the Use inferred grammar in absence of DTD/Schema
2. (Just for android) Change the opening  tag of strings.xml to:

   ```
   <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   ```

May not be the answers for you, but hey, hope it helps.